# Is $E(xy) \geq E(x) E(y)$?

Tags: statistics

Is $E(xy) \geq E(x) E(y)$ always?  Where $E$ means expectation.

Intuitively I feel like covariance should always be nonnegative, but I cannot prove why.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not true. For example, let $x$ be $0$ or $1$ with equal probability of $0.5$, and let $y = 1 - x$. Then $E(xy) = 0$, but $E(x)E(y) = 0.25$.

About the second sentence, it is also false. For example, let $y = -x$. Then the covariance will be negative if $x$ has non-zero variance.

Comment: Good point, thanks.  But regular variance is always nonnegative right?

Comment: @badatmath Yes. The regular variance is always non-negative because it is an expectation of a non-negative quantity.

Comment: Oh right, because it can be written as $E((X - E(X))^2)$.  Gotcha.